# Change specific value inside an array with find. React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
let array = [{7: 10}, {10: 9}, {8: 5}, {3: 4}, {6: 7}]
```

I would like to change specific values inside of this array of objects,
I know how to do this :

```
array.find(
(item, index) => Object.keys(item) === 7 
? 
console.log('I would like to delete this object or change its value = ' + Object.values(item))
: 
null
);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here example. You can make it as function by param instead '7'.

```
let array = [{7: 10}, {10: 9}, {8: 5}, {3: 4}, {6: 7}];

array.forEach(
    (item) => {
        if (Object.keys(item).find(key => key === '7'))
            item['7'] = 8
    });

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Is it possible to delete the Object ?

Comment: Yes, you can use splice.

let array = [{7: 10}, {10: 9}, {8: 5}, {3: 4}, {6: 7}];

array.forEach(
    (item, index) => {
        if (Object.keys(item).find(key => key === '7'))
            array.splice(index, 1);
    });

console.log(array);

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
// Find the index you want to change
const index = array.findIndex(element => {
    return Object.keys(element) == 7
})

//assign it with new value
array[index] = {5:6}
```